# Vue js axios get request error - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: vue.js, axios, yii

I have done a simple get request using axios as follows

```
axios
      .get('my api',{
        withCredentials: true,
        headers:{
            'Authorization': 'token'
        },
        params:{
            id:this.$route.params.id,
            identity:this.$route.params.identity
        }
    }
```

And in the server side i added my local host ip and all to the allowed domains

```
http://localhost:8080
```

and the below things are my cors config

```
'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST','GET','OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"],
```

But i am still getting the error

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The auth token is not getting on the server i think.When i try to disable the token , then it is working.So the token is making the issue.How can i solve this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer.It was an issue of using cors along with authentication.I just added my cors filters above the authentication like below.Before it was below the authentication

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
        $behaviors['corsFilter']=[
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors'  => [
                'Origin'=> ['http://localhost:8080'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['Authorization'],
            ],
        ];
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => JwtHttpBearerAuth::class,
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```